# How to fill objects with protected constructor and private property settes?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a domain object like this :

```
public class Document 
{
   public string Index { get; private set; }
   public string Title { get; private set; }
   public string Content { get; private set; }

   public Document (string index, string title, string content)
   {
       // some domain rule here
       Index = index;
       Title = title; 
       Content = content; 
   }
 
   protected Document() {}
}
```

Now I want to construct objects of type `Document` and fill their properties when I am fetching data from storage without any ORM like Dapper.

I want to know how do the Dapper or JsonConvert fill objects using protected constructors and private property setters?

Answer (score 2):

The constructor that does fill the fields is not protected, it's public.

Some packages are smart enough or bring attributes so you can teach them to use those constructors, some others just use reflection. You can write to private properties using reflection.